# Call JS function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am unable to call a function from HTML file. This seems simple and my code matches what I've seen in similar SO answers, but I am missing something still. I know the JS is loading/running because the game in the canvas is working. 
Edit: Chrome console returns "testFunction is not defined" meaning the JS is NOT loaded. Why?

This is a test in the JS file:

```
function testFunction(){
    alert("It works!");
}
```

and it's called from the HTML like so:

```
<button type="button" onclick="testFunction()" id="testButton">Test</button>
```

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't match your code

Comment: Oops you're right just updated.

Comment: Consider keeping your Javascript and HTML separate. [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) should help.

Comment: They are separate. The script is called externally.

Comment: Have a read of the first link that I provided.

Comment: Sorry I can't see your update on the fiddle

Comment: JS fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/

Comment: Check Niet's answer. http://jsfiddle.net/SeAGU/103/

Comment: @Xotic750, I am reading up, thanks. Does this mean that I should not use "onclick" in HTML at all, but set that behavior from the external JS?

Comment: That would be my personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using JSFiddle, your code is wrapped in an "onLoad" function (unless you specifically tell it otherwise).

Functions defined inside functions exist only in that function, so your `testFunction`, for example, is only accessible in the `onLoad` function that is your JS block of code. HTML from the outside can't access it.

Try changing "onLoad" to "no wrap - body" in the relevant option on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) examples.

[Javascript events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

Like this using [`on` + handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick), is one way and most compatible.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="testButton">Test</button>
```

Javascript

```
function testFunction() {
    alert("It works!");
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('testButton').onclick = testFunction;
};
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qbM52/)

Or using the modern method [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Javascript

```
function testFunction() {
    alert("It works!");
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', testFunction, false);
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/L5kYv/)

[GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)